# Tomcat log error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.<init>() in my SpringMVC project

Tags: java, spring-mvc, error-handling, tomcat8

My project questionnaire is develop based on jdk1.8 tomcat8,in my local machine it runs normality.No errors found. but when i deployed it on the server，the project sometimes runs normality，sometime runs abnormal.if runs abnormity i restart the tomcat then it become normal. I do not found the reason, the only message i get from tomcat logs like this:

```
[http-nio-80-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/questionnaire] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [int]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.<init>()] with root cause
```

java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: int.()

```
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:102)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
```

The  environment of the server is jdk 1.8 tomcat8,is similar to my local machine. Did someone help me ? thanks a lot

Comment: Somewhere in you configurations you seem to have tagged an `int` variable with `@Autowired`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your model on the controller method hasn't no args construction method, so the creation of failure.please check again.

Comment: you mean should i add : no args construction method  in  Profile.java and Mood.java , public Profile() {  }  and  Public Mood() {  }  but I'm a little confused. In these two java files, i hasn't add self define construction method, so the default constructor is no args, Don't need me added it manually

Comment: @nicoleljc1227 Could you tell me your QQ number? I will help you.

Comment: sorry I see a answer on your log just now that you want to instantiate int.that is not is a class.so dont has construction method.in your request about "questionnaire"